# tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with xxx values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of

Tags: tensorflow

I'm implementing this (https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py) by TensorFlow. My code is as follows.

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import tensorflow as tf

def weight_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def conv2d(x, W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

def max_pool_2x2(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
    strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('data', one_hot=True)
    x = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, 784])
    y_ = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, 10])
    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

    x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1,28,28,1])

    W_conv1 = weight_variable([3, 3, 1, 32])
    b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])
    W_conv2 = weight_variable([3, 3, 32, 32])
    b_conv2 = bias_variable([32])
    W_fc1 = weight_variable([12*12*32, 128])
    b_fc1 = bias_variable([128])
    W_fc2 = weight_variable([128, 10])
    b_fc2 = bias_variable([10])

    h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
    h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_conv1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
    h_pool = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)
    keep_prob1 = tf.placeholder("float")
    h_drop1 = tf.nn.dropout(h_pool, keep_prob1)
    h_flat = tf.reshape(h_drop1, [-1, 12*12*32])
    h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)
    keep_prob2 = tf.placeholder("float")
    h_drop2 = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob2)

    y_conv = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h_drop2, W_fc2) + b_fc2)

    cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_*tf.log(y_conv))
    train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    for i in range(20000):
        batch = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
        if i%100 == 0:
            train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
                x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob1: 1.0, keep_prob2: 1.0})
            print("step %d, training accuracy %g"%(i, train_accuracy))
        train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob1: 0.25, keep_prob2: 0.5})

    print("test accuracy %g"%accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
        x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels, keep_prob1: 1.0, keep_prob2: 1.0}))
```

When I ran, the following error occurred at a flatten layer. I tried to match the input shape, but the error message said "a tensor with 313600 values" which I had no idea where this came from.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/Projects/projectname/keras/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 972, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/Users/username/Projects/projectname/keras/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 954, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/Users/username/Projects/projectname/keras/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors.py", line 463, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 313600 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 4608
     [[Node: Reshape_1 = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](dropout/mul, Reshape_1/shape)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mnist_tensorflow.py", line 60, in <module>
    x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob1: 1.0, keep_prob2: 1.0})
  File "/Users/username/Projects/projectname/keras/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 559, in eval
    return _eval_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, session)
  File "/Users/username/Projects/projectname/keras/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3761, in _eval_using_default_session
    return session.run(tensors, feed_dict)
  File "/Users/username/Projects/projectname/keras/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 717, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/Users/username/Projects/projectname/keras/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 915, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/Users/username/Projects/projectname/keras/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 965, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/Users/username/Projects/projectname/keras/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 985, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 313600 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 4608
     [[Node: Reshape_1 = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](dropout/mul, Reshape_1/shape)]]

Caused by op 'Reshape_1', defined at:
  File "mnist_tensorflow.py", line 44, in <module>
    h_flat = tf.reshape(h_drop1, [-1, 12*12*32])
  File "/Users/username/Projects/projectname/keras/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 1977, in reshape
    name=name)
  File "/Users/username/Projects/projectname/keras/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 749, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/Users/username/Projects/projectname/keras/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2380, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/Users/username/Projects/projectname/keras/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1298, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Input to reshape is a tensor with 313600 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 4608
     [[Node: Reshape_1 = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](dropout/mul, Reshape_1/shape)]]
```

I've checked the similar question ([Error: Tensorflow CNN dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38397258/error-tensorflow-cnn-dimension)) and I confirmed that I defined the target image for reshaping/flattening. Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Comment: Thanks. if I type `h_flat` after `h_flat = tf.reshape(h_drop1, [-1, 12*12*32])`, the output is `<tf.Tensor 'Reshape_4:0' shape=(?, 4608) dtype=float32>`.  Or, if I type `h_flat.get_shape()`, then the output is `TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(4608)])`.

Comment: can you provide output for `print(h_pool) ` and `print(h_drop1)`?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The output for `print(h_pool)` is `Tensor("MaxPool:0", shape=(?, 14, 14, 32), dtype=float32)` and the output for `print(h_drop1)` is `Tensor("dropout/mul:0", shape=(?, 14, 14, 32), dtype=float32)`.

Comment: As in above layers your shape is `14, 14, 32`, hence you should reshape data accordingly. So change `h_flat = tf.reshape(h_drop1, [-1, 14*14*32])`

Comment: also change `W_fc1 = weight_variable([14*14*32, 128])`

Comment: Thank you. Now I found that I should set 'VALID', not 'SAME' in conv2 so that I can make 12, 12, 32 shape before flatting operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake was very simple. I found that I should set 'VALID', not 'SAME' in conv2 so that I can make 12, 12, 32 shape before flatting operation. Thank you turtle to help me out.